# removeEventListener not working from variable

Tags: javascript

short querySelector

```
function __(el){
  return document.querySelectorAll(el);
};
```

example of vars

```
img = _('.thumbnail img'),
    canvas = _('#cs')
```

this has been updated to show the function inside this

```
img.addEventListener('mousemove', function colorCatcher(e){

spin = document.getElementsByClassName('spin');
parts = spin[0].className.split('-');
if(parts[4] == 'left'){
  preview = __('.stripes'),x = '',y = '';  
}else{
  preview = _('.strike-through'),x = '',y = '';  
}


  if(e.offsetX) {
    x = e.offsetX;
    y = e.offsetY; 
  }


  else if(e.layerX) {
    x = e.layerX;
    y = e.layerY;
  }


useCanvas(canvas,img,function(){

    var p = canvas.getContext('2d')
    .getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;

    if(preview.length == 2){
      preview[0].style.background = rgbToHex(p[0],p[1],p[2]);
      preview[1].style.background = rgbToHex(p[0],p[1],p[2]);
    }else{
      preview.style.background = rgbToHex(p[0],p[1],p[2]);
    }
  });
}, false);
```

I cannot figure out how to do removeEventListener on the above.

I have tried stuff like:

```
img.removeEventListener('mousemove', img.colorCatcher, false);
document.removeEventListener('mousemove', img.colorCatcher, 
window.removeEventListener('mousemove', img.colorCatcher, false);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to specify the target on the `removeEventListener` in this case it should be:

```
img.removeEventListener('mousemove', colorCatcher, false);
```

Another thing is in IE and Safari you need to specify exactly the same signature of the addEventListener otherwise the event is not going to be removed so if you added an event as:

```
// Added as
img.addEventListener('mousemove', colorCatcher, false); 
// Should be removed as
img.removeEventListener('mousemove', colorCatcher, false);

// Added as
img.addEventListener('mousemove', colorCatcher); 
// Should be removed as
img.removeEventListener('mousemove', colorCatcher);
```

**Edit**

You need to make sure your function is defined such as:

```
function colorCatcher(){
  // Actions here
}

// Added as
img.addEventListener('mousemove', colorCatcher, false); 
// Should be removed as
img.removeEventListener('mousemove', colorCatcher, false);
```

Comment: I've tried this and got Uncaught ReferenceError: colorCatcher is not defined.  
I have updated my question to show inside the function in case It wasn't enough info

Comment: yup, I assumed this last night is why I made sure to put the extra in my question.  Putting the function outside of it resolved my issue.  Thank you mitogh